# Java Проблема со сравнением строк с русскими словами

Tags: java

Есть *.txt файл в котором записаны слова на латинице и кириллице. Я читаю строки из файла с сравниваю их содержимое с заданной с помощью String.contains. С Латиницей все замечательно работает, а русские слова не находит.

```
HashMap<String,Description> map = new HashMap<String,Description>();
    String sourceFile = "f:/File.txt";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
    String line;
    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String [] word = line.split("\\|");
        map.put(word[0],new Description(word[1],word[2]));
    }
    reader.close();
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String st = reader1.readLine();
    String result;
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (HashMap.Entry<String,Description> pair: map.entrySet())
    {
        String temp = pair.getValue().getLesson();
        if (temp.contains(st))
        {
            result = pair.getKey()+" : "+pair.getValue().getLesson()+" / "+pair.getValue().getLink();
            results.add(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это вероятно потому, что java для внутреннего представления строк использует UTF-8, а файл в какой-то другой кодировке. С латинскими буквами проблем нет. Они везде одинаковые. А вот остальные... Короче, при открытии или чтении файла можно как-то указать в какой он кодировке. Есть специальные конструкторы с соответствующим параметром. Используйте его с указанием кодировки своего файла.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно явно указать кодировку читаемого файла. При помощи FileReader этого сделать нельзя, поэтому используй  `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), "кодировка_твоего_файла")`. Кодировка твоего файла скорее всего лежит в пределе: **"UTF-8"**, **"CP1251"** или **"CP866"**. Но у тебя есть ещё одна проблема в коде. Читать символы национальных алфавитов в java-программе из консоли вообще идея плохая. Можно заменить `new InputStreamReader(System.in)` на `new InputStreamReader(System.in, "кодировка_консоли")`, где кодировка консоли будет **"CP866"** или **"CP1251"** (но может быть и другая). Однако это не кросплатформенное решение, что противоречит философии java-программы.